# Live XML Feed to MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, xml

I already know how to parse live XML feeds in Java, what i would like help on is placing that data in a MySQL database.

I would then want to display that data on a webpage, but i guess that may be a different question all together.

Comment: So your question is how to write to a MySQL database in Java? That's very broad. What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I have not tried, i was hoping to be pointed in the right direction. i will be getting a live feed which may update every 15 min, i then would like that data parsed to update the data base around every 15 min also.

Answer (score 0):

You might try a tutorial like [Using JDBC with MySQL, Getting Started](http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3417381) to get started.

That should get you to a point where you're ready to ask more specific questions.

Comment: Specifics about what you want to do. All we know so far is that you want to write data (parsed XML) to a database. The best answer to such a broad question is a general introduction, as linked above.

Answer (score 0):

There are three separate parts to your (very fuzzy) question:

1. Parsing XML - you'll need a DOM, SAX, or StaX parser
2. XML storage in MySQL - JDBC is the foundation of all relation database interactions in Java.  You don't say if storing the XML as a CLOB is sufficient, or if you intend to maintain the hierarchical nature in the database.
3. Rendering on a web page.  There are several templating solutions you can use, such as JSPs using JSTL, XSL-T transformation of XML into HTML, or Velocity templates to generate HTML.

Comment: Proceed to steps 2 and 3, then.